# Is it unsafe to put router into "DHCP and NAT" mode?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, internet, router

When I was trying to get my Raspberry Pi online, in airport utility I put my router in DHCP and NAT mode and entered ports (80). Did I open up these ports to the internet? Would this be unsafe to do?

If I did not open up these ports to the internet, how can I open them up? 
(just to know what I should not do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by putting it in DHCP mode you did open up your router to the outside world. Assuming you have changed the default password on your router then when someone tried to connect to your IP Address then it would simply send them to your routers webpage. In theory you would be safe from 5 year olds but it is not recommended.
Just for some extra information you would only want to open Port 80, Enable DHCP Mode or enable Virtual server if you were planning to host a server from inside your network that you wanted access to from the outside.
Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the information, very usefull. Although that is what I want to do, host a server inside my network that's accessible from the outside. Can you suggest any security measures i should consider besides a strong router password?

Comment: If you want to host a server then on your router just set up either virtual server or port forwarding (depending on your router) and direct it to your server's local IP address. From there whenever you try to access your global ip then you will be directed to your servers webpage. If you do this correctly then you would only have access to the router's login page from local network.

Comment: I've got an airport time capsule as a router. The airport utility has limited configuration. I'll try to look into setting up a virtual server, I got some basic notes on this. Thank you. Any further recommendations are welcome.